# bind9 dont start On Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, systemd, systemctl

when I install bind9 on Kali Linux,cant start or stop it. when use `systemctl status bind9.service` for view status it, I see message that say Unit bind9.service could not be found.

```
root@sarvdata:~# systemctl status bind9.service 
Unit bind9.service could not be found.
```

I install bind9 again

```
root@sarvdata:~# sudo apt install bind9
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
bind9 is already the newest version (1:9.18.16-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbind9-161 libdns1107 libisc1104 libisccc161 libisccfg163 liblwres161
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1648 not upgraded.
```

but it could not solve my problem. I try it on another Linux distribution like ubuntu and debian, It work correctly. just Does not work on Kali Linux...

Comment: Look inside the package with `dpkg -l ...` – does it contain _any_ .service files at all? (Or, for that matter, anything else?)

Comment: Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  bind9          1:9.18.16-1  amd64        Internet Domain Name Server  @u1686_grawity

Comment: Sorry, that should've been `dpkg -L`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
Unit bind9.service could not be found.
```

That means that `systemd` cannot find the unit-file. That means you have to create, link or copy the unit file or start `bind9` another way; most likely `/etc/init.d/bind9 start`.

Answer (score 0):

on Kali linux bind9's service is called "named", not "bind9"

so you need to do:

```
systemctl status named
```

Comment: yessss, it worked! tnks.